# Insert template into every source file in an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Is there a tool, option or script to insert a custom template into the header of every existing source file within an Eclipse project?`

---

*Some background information*

I have very recently open-sourced a small application written for a university assignment. Initially the source files did not require any explicit license or author information. But now I am releasing the code I would like to place this information in the header of each Java source file.

I know Eclipse has the capability of inserting a custom template in each new file, and I will be doing this from now on. But there is around 60 existing .java files within which I wish to place this header. While that is not a huge number, I really don't fancy repeating the same cut and paste operation 60 times if there's a lazier way to do it.

---

P.S. I couldn't think up any better tags for this question, suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check out JAutodoc on sourceforge. http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Specifically, check out the section entitled **File Header**

Hope this helps.